# adding a class via python

Tags: python, html

Having a such html

```
somehtml = "<p>Here is my solution: </p><pre><code> some code here </code> </pre> <pre>this is not a code</pre>"
```

Via python I want to add class "foo" to those `<pre>` tags which contains a child `<code>` thus my output will be :

```
somehtml = "<p>Here is my solution: </p><pre class="foo"><code> some code here </code> </pre> <pre>this is not a code</pre>"
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Are you creating the HTML yourself?

Comment: yes I create it via wmd editor to markdown and convert at the server level to html and for google-code-prettify syntax highlighting, I need to add "prettyprint" class to pre tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), it could be done like this:

```
import lxml.html as lh
import io

somehtml = "<p>Here is my solution: </p><pre><code> some code here </code> </pre> <pre>this is not a code</pre>"

doc=lh.parse(io.BytesIO(somehtml))
root=doc.getroot() 
pres=root.xpath('//pre/code/..')

for pre in pres:
    pre.attrib['class']='foo'
print(lh.tostring(root))
```

yields

```
<html><body><p>Here is my solution: </p><pre class="foo"><code> some code here </code> </pre> <pre>this is not a code</pre></body></html>
```

Comment: File "deneme.py", line 11, in <module>
    ''')
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1317, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:37255)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 289, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:104028)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 212, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:103335)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 198, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise_eval_error (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:103207)
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression

Comment: I get such error, I think there is something worng with the string inside xpath.

Comment: @Hellnar: Sorry about that -- my mistake. The above edit should not have that error.